# Curl php not loading website style

Tags: php, curl, iframe

I used below code to display another website on my site

```
  $turl = $_GET['turl'];
  $ch = curl_init($turl);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; 
  en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  $data = curl_exec( $ch );

 echo $data;
```

but when I tried to display facebook or youtube the result looks like-

[image]

Comment: The styling is probably in a CSS file somewhere. So that needs to be curled separately. Also javascript may be in separate files.

Comment: Well of course it does ... every single relative URL used anywhere in those sites now gets resolved to an absolute URL that points to _your_ domain. You would have to first of all find all those relative URLs, and modify them accordingly.

Comment: But even if you fixed that, you should not expect these sites to “work” as they usually do - because all functionality that relies on cookies for example will of course also not work.

Comment: You can use iframe instead

Comment: In my case code is working in perfect condition on local server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `curl` only gets html (source code) of specified url and i think styles are addressed relatively on server(not full path). 
this is why no style has been found .
you can also check console in google chrome or firefox by pressing F12 on each browsers and see errors.